# Why reachability of IP address never gets called back?

Tags: ios, ip, automatic-ref-counting, ip-address, reachability

I've been struggling for two days for now with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077345/reachability-of-ip-address

---

Finally I found a solution, so if anyone had the same problem, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research, I found a solution.
The bottleneck is to invoke the current reachability status even in "listening" mode, when initialized with an IP adddress (like the one snippet below, without the rest application context).

```
if (isAddressReachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.eppz.reachability.workaround", NULL), ^
    {
        SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
        if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(self.reachabilityRef, &flags))
        {
            //'Manual' invocation of callback functionality.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ //Dispatch delegate callback on the main thread.
            {
                [self parseFlags:flags];
                [self.delegate reachabilityChanged:self];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

More detailed at: http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-ip-address-doesnt-work/

Comment: Why not post this as an answer to the other question you linked to?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Had the exact same problem (still in iOS 7).

Comment: @David That post is deleted.

Comment: @rpitting I suggest use http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-blocks/ (put on GitHub at https://github.com/eppz/eppz-reachability) that has this issue solved, also pretty clean to use.